# Can I evaluate a block against a Binding object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm trying to pass the context in which an exception was raised to an `Exception` subclass, in order to use this context to generate an informative error message.  I recognize that I could pass individual pieces of data to the Exception, but I am wondering how I can pass and use the whole context.

I know I can capture the context with `Kernel#binding`.  The Ruby 2.0 docs for class `Binding` list a single method: `eval`.  This allows you to evaluate a `String` in the context captured by a `Binding`.  I am wondering whether it is possible to evaluate a block in the context of a binding.  I would use this as follows:

```
class MyError < StandardError

  def initialize(str: nil, context: nil)
    @str = str; @context = context
    super(str)
  end

  def to_s
    @str ? @str : @context.**SOME_METHOD** { "Error: x == #{x}" }
  end

end 

x = 5
raise MyError.new(context: binding)

=> Error: x == #{5}
```

I've tried both `instance_exec` and `instance_eval`, for **SOME_METHOD**, neither of which work.  Is there any way to do this?  Or, is there some reason that it is a bad idea to generate the error message from the whole context, rather than individual pieces of data from the environment?

Answer (score 3):

Use `eval(string, binding)` to run Ruby code with given variable bindings. For your case, you can rewrite `to_s` method as followed:

```rb
def to_s
  @str ? @str : eval('"Error: x == #{x}"', @context)
end
```

Note that you'll need `'"some_string"'` form to prevent string interpolation before the parameter is passed to `eval`.

If you want to evaluate block with some binding, you'll have to assign the block to a variable and `eval` the block like `block.call`. Now you have two binding environments, one for the variable `block` and another for the variables in the block. As there's no method such as `join`, `combine` for `Binding`, it seems that you cannot achieve this with `Kernel#eval` or `Binding#eval`. And besides, a block captures its bindings where it was defined. When you call `eval('block.call', some_binding)`, it ignores the binding passed in.

However, you can use `Object#instance_eval` and pass the block in with the form `instance_eval(&block)`, that will evaluate the block in the bindings of the Class's instance methods. So you can create proper bindings for the block with the context you captured.

```rb
class BlockEnv
  def initialize(context, &block)
    # remove instance methods inherited from Object to minimize the impact
    # remove this if unnecessary
    BlockEnv.instance_methods
      .reject{|m|
        [:object_id, :call, :instance_eval, :method_missing].include?(m) ||
          m.to_s !~ /^[a-z]\w*$/i }
      .each do |m|
        eval("undef :#{m}")
      end
    @context = context
    @block = block
  end
  def call
    self.instance_eval(&@block)
  end
  def method_missing(name)
    eval(name.to_s, @context) rescue super
  end
end

class MyError < StandardError
  def initialize(str: nil, context: nil)
    @str = str; @context = context
    super(str)
  end

  def to_s
    @str ? @str : BlockEnv.new(@context){ "Error: x == #{x}" }.call
  end
end

x = 5
raise MyError.new(context: binding)
```

Comment: very cool, I will use this.  It's very strange to me though that there is no more direct way to do this.